# Is there a specific way to define language grammar?

Tags: syntax, format, grammar

If I were to want to create a new programming language, is there a specific file format or extension used to define the grammar of this new language? Or should I just use a plain text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for might be a [metasyntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntax) notation, sometimes also called "formal grammar".

A common notation to describe at least certain types of formal languages is [Extended Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). It defines the grammar by means of "production rules" that gradually expand a "start symbol" into any valid expressions in the described language.

This format is, however, mainly a notation (i.e. it describes *how* you write down the language description, even when you're writing on paper). It is not so much a "file format" in the sense that there would be a standard extension for it.

Comment: I think Python uses the `.gram` file extension. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Grammar/python.gram